# @Autowired Processor is null

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka

I'm working wit an OOTB example for Spring Cloud Stream.

I have this code in my main.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableBinding(Processor.class)
@EnableSchemaRegistryClient
public class AvroKafkaApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        SpringApplication.run(AvroKafkaApplication.class, args);
     }
}
```

When I throw something into this, the Processor class inside My producer class is null.

```
@Service
public class AvroProducer {

    @Autowired
    private Processor processor;

    public void produceEmployeeDetails(int empId, String firstName, String lastName) {

        // creating employee details
        Employee employee = new Employee();
        employee.setId(empId);
        employee.setFirstName(firstName);
        employee.setLastName(lastName);
        employee.setDepartment("IT");
        employee.setDesignation("Engineer");

        // creating partition key for kafka topic
        EmployeeKey employeeKey = new EmployeeKey();
        employeeKey.setId(empId);
        employeeKey.setDepartmentName("IT");

        Message<Employee> message = MessageBuilder.withPayload(employee)
            .setHeader(KafkaHeaders.MESSAGE_KEY, employeeKey)
            .build();

        processor.output()
            .send(message);
    }

}
```

The @Autowired annotation works fine, because I don't have an error with the functionallity, but the process variables is null any time.

The base project can be cloned from here:
https://github.com/eugenp/tutorials/tree/master/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/spring-cloud-stream-kafka

Any ideas on this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

I just downloaded your project and it works fine for me...

```
$ http post localhost:8080/employees/1/John/Doe
HTTP/1.1 200 
Content-Length: 33
Content-Type: text/plain;charset=UTF-8
Date: Wed, 11 Dec 2019 21:52:38 GMT

Sent employee details to consumer
```

> 2019-12-11 16:52:38.131  INFO 24203 --- [container-0-C-1] com.baeldung.consumer.AvroConsumer       : Let's process employee details: {"id": 1, "firstName": "John", "lastName": "Doe", "department": "IT", "designation": "Engineer"}

The only change I made was to fix the `concurrency` property in the yaml (missing `consumer` element), but that wouldn't have made a difference.